# Mocking service in a component - mock ignored

Tags: angular, service, mocking, angular2-testing

This time I'm trying to mock a service (that does http calls) to test a component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ub-funding-plan',
  templateUrl: './funding-plan.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./funding-plan.component.css'],
  providers: [FundingPlanService]
})
export class FundingPlanComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private fundingPlanService: FundingPlanService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.reloadFundingPlans();
  }

  reloadFundingPlans() {
    this.fundingPlanService.getFundingPlans().subscribe((fundingPlans: FundingPlan[]) => {
      this.fundingPlans = fundingPlans;
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

The [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#component-with-dependency) (version 2.0.0) explains that you should mock the service. Using the same `TestBed` configuration:

```
describe('Component: FundingPlan', () => {
  class FundingPlanServiceMock {
    getFundingPlans(): Observable<FundingPlan> { return Observable.of(testFundingPlans) }
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [FundingPlanComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: FundingPlanService, useClass: FundingPlanServiceMock },
      ]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FundingPlanComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  fit('should display a title', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(titleElement.nativeElement.textContent).toContain('Funding Plans');
  });

});
```

When I run the test, I get:

```
Error: No provider for AuthHttp!
```

that is indeedused by the actual service, but not by the mock. So for some reason, the mock is not injected or used.

Any advise? Thanks!

Answer (score 83, accepted):

It's because of

```
@Component({
  providers: [FundingPlanService] <===
})
```

The `@Component.providers` takes precedence over any global providers, since using the `@Component.providers` makes the provider scoped only to the component. In the test, Angular creates the mocked service in the module scope and the original service in the component scope.

To solve this problem, Angular provides the `TestBed.overrideComponent` method, where we can override things like templates and providers at the component level.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [FundingPlanComponent]
});
TestBed.overrideComponent(FundingPlanComponent, {
  set: {
    providers: [
      { provide: FundingPlanService, useClass: FundingPlanServiceMock },
    ]
  }
})
```

See also:

- [Override a component's providers - Angular Testing Docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#override-component-providers)

Comment: The provided link would have been extremely useful, but it's kind of broken. Did you mean this one? [Override a component's provider](https://angular.io/guide/testing#override-a-components-providers)

Comment: Please note that in order to get an instance of a mocked service (to e.g. spy on its methods) instead of using `TestBed.inject(FundingPlanService)` you'll need to do it like this
`fundingPlanService = <any>fixture.debugElement.injector.get(FundingPlanService);`

Comment: Thanks @amost that's exactly what I missed.